# Infragistics XamDataChart: How to use NumericXAxis for CategorySeries like ColumnSeries, AreaSeries and so on?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts, infragistics

Title of my question probably is descriptive enough, yet here is the rest:

I need to plot histograms and area charts for some numeric values. I already managed to do it partially using a `CategoryXAxis`, the only option which `ColumnSeries` Supports.

Unfortunately labels don't show good enough (Position, Spacing, ...) and also Tick Markers are meant to be for category data and show between Columns.

As the task looks really trivial, and i need to do this many times with different options, i was thinking maybe there is a way to do this using a `NumericXAxis` which is pretty simple and meant to be used for numeric data.

Unfortunately i don't see a way to convert use `NumericXAxis` for `ColumnSeries`? So I hope someone could help me on this.

Requirements: I use .Net Framework 4.0, C#, WPF

Note: I'm more interested in Code-Behind rather than XAML.